# laravel failed to detect mimes txt intermittenly

Tags: php, laravel-5, file-upload

I have a weird case here where I can't upload some txt file

I created 5 txt files in the desktop and tried to upload to my server with laravel.
The content and how I create the files are all the same by right-clicking and click new document and another method is copy-paste and just rename the files.

Here's the code to check the file.

```
$rules = ['upload_file' => 'required|file|mimes:txt|max:15000'];
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules);
if($validator->fails()){  // check if there's any error
    foreach($validator->errors()->all() as $key => $value) {
       @$errMess .= $value;
    }
    $message = ['message' => $errMess ];
    // show the error
    return response()->json($status);
}
//else continue to upload file to server
```

The failed error from Validator is

> The upload file must be a file of type: txt.

I have checked everything like permission of the temp files, the differences of the file with `dd()`, php error and I still can't figure it out

Here's the dd of the succeed and failed files.

[Success DD Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4vdS.png)
[Failed DD Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p57Y.png)

Comment: Bro mime type should be `text/plain` or `text/*`. You can check the mime type before upload file useing `$request->file('file')->getMimeType()`. I think you need to use `text` rather than `txt`

Comment: by using validator from laravel, I know there are mimeType (text/plain) and mimes (file extension). I tried both validation as I upload the file , the file is clearly with mimetype : text/plain with extension : .txt but still stuck with the error. it seems something wrong with the laravel validation, it is still happening till now